# MySQL: Issue joining two tables

Tags: mysql

So basically what I'm trying to do is select 5 random rows from the category_event table, then match the fk_event_id from the category_event table with the id from the events table, and finally order the 5 random rows by start_time from the events table.

I have 25 rows in the category_event table with fk_category_id=2, but when I run the query sometimes it returns 5 rows, next time 4 rows, next time 5 rows, next time 3 rows, etc. It should be 5 every time...

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT fk_event_id 
   FROM category_event 
   WHERE fk_category_id=2 AND status = 'enabled' 
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
) c 
INNER JOIN events e 
ON e.id = c.fk_event_id 
ORDER BY e.start_time;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please show some data from the tables. Perhaps you're inadvertently limiting the results in the WHERE clause or due to in the INNER JOIN.

Comment: fk_event_id looks like it should have a foreign key constraint to events 'id' column, is that correct?  (because the symptoms you describe sould like 'some rows without matching events')

Comment: Can you provide table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had rows in category_event that had fk_event_id's that were pointing to non existing rows in events.

Everything's good now :)

Comment: db is not magic you know...calling it fk_ does not make it into a foreign key ;)

Comment: I mean...you should add a foreign key constraint to prevent it from happening again